# Optimize Transaction of high-definition images in Slider

Tags: jquery, css

I did a parallax slider that works well, however the images are in high definition, I am using CSS3 "transaction" to navigate in the slides.

```
transaction: 2s margin-left;
```

the images to be very large, this waging transition.
Like to leave softer.

My doubts, I have to smush the images or change the type of transaction with some javascript plugin?

Comment: There is no `transaction` in css - I guess you mean `transition`? Also lacks a reproducible code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Parallax](http://blog.keithclark.co.uk/pure-css-parallax-websites/) and [CSS `transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition).

Ans yes, a code example is always recommended to get a satisfying answer.